# How to Install a module that needs an instance per something else that is registered in Castle Windsor

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am trying to get the hang of IoC and DI and am using Castle Windsor.  I have an object I have created that can be multiply instantiated but over different generic types.  For example

```
MyType<Generic, Generic2>
```

on Installation of MyType's assembly

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof (IMyType<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof (MyType<>)));
```

Then in my main modules initialization I install MyTypes module with MyTypeInstaller which is a IWindsorInstaller.

Then I am manually resolving the various types of MyType that I want (this will actually be spread around different installers).  But something like

```
container.Resolve<IMyType<type1, type2>();
```

That creates an actual instance of MyType registered for the generic types passed in.

This works fine, I get the instances of MyType<,> I need created.

Now, finally I have another module I have created that I will install last.  I want to say,

```
container.ResolveAll<IMyType<,>>()
```

then create this instances of this new object for each object that exists.

However I cant seem to resolve all of the IMyTypes<,> without knowing the concrete types that each one were instantiated as.

At any rate, it is possible I am just doing this wrong and want feedback in general as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if `MyType<T1,T2>` can only be instantiated once for each combination of T1,T2 then you should be registering it is a Singleton.

Second, You cannot call strongly type container methods (like `ResolveAll<T>`) with an open generic - it MUST be a closed type.

Third, MyType is an open generic type and the number of closed generic classes is infinite (generic type constraints are not considered by the container). So, as far as the container is concerned you can call `Resolve<ANYTHING, ANYTHINGELSE>` and it will attempt to provide a `MyType<ANYTHING,ANYTHINGELSE>` for you. If ANYTHING and ANYTHINGELSE don't satisfy the type constraints then you will simply get a run time error.

Even if you could call `ResolveAll<IMyType<,>>()` what would you expect it to return given that you have registered an open generic implementation?

Comment: What i want is a way to Resolve all of the various types that have been instantiated under the open generic definition.

Comment: Castle Windsor does not provide a way for you to query for the objects it is tracking -- this would imply knowledge of the container, which defeats the purpose of IoC. If you want to track instantiation yourself then you could create your own factory or facility to achieve that.

Comment: Phil thanks for the input.  Is there a design that works better with ioc for this kind of thing?  Basically i have a module (a) that needs to know about all of the types of another class (b) that have been instantiated but class b shouldnt know or care about module a. i feel like ioc is a good fit since it already knows the information that module a needs. I would be happy to not interact with the container directly if there is an appropriate pattern.  Thanks

Comment: There are a few ways to do tracking. Most basic would be to register a creation handler using OnCreate. If the components are Singletons and not released, this may suffice. As mentioned, other ways would be to create your own factory or facility. It's hard to suggest an appropriate pattern without more information. Which ever way, it should be pretty straight forward just make sure properly handle releasing.